# ViewModel model Member is not updated in the UI after OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, maui

I am navigating to a detail page, passing Id as a parameter, retrieving it and looking up the detail model from a service.  That part works fine.  However, in the page the model object within the ViewModel is not updated even though it is ObservableProperty.

Defined DI:

```cs
CreateRoutePageMapping<MembersPage, MembersViewModel>(),
CreateRoutePageMapping<MemberPage, MemberViewModel>(),
```

Defined model:

```cs
public partial class MemberModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string firstName;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string lastName;

    public MemberModel()
    {
        FirstName = String.Empty;
        LastName = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Defined ViewModel:

```cs
public partial class MemberViewModel : BaseViewModel, IQueryAttributable
{
    readonly IMembersService _membersService;
    readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

    [ObservableProperty]
    int id;

    [ObservableProperty]
    MemberModel member = new();

    partial void OnIdChanged(int value)
    {
        Task.Run(async () => await GetMemberAsync(id: Id));
    }

    public MemberViewModel(
        IMembersService membersService,
        IConnectivity connectivity,
        IDialogService dialogService,
        IStringLocalizer<ProjectStrings> localizer
        ) : base(connectivity, dialogService, localizer)
    {
        _membersService = membersService;
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task GetMemberAsync(int id)
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;

        try
        {
            if (!(await HasInternetAccessAsync()))
                return;

            IsBusy = true;

            Member = await _membersService.GetMemberAsync(id: id);
            //OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Member));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Member.FirstName));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Member.LastName));
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error retrieving member: {ex.Message}");
        }

        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

    void IQueryAttributable.ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        int id = (int)query["id"];
        Id = id;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id));
    }
}
```

Defined Page:

```cs
using static CommunityToolkit.Maui.Markup.GridRowsColumns;

public partial class MemberPage : BaseContentPage<MemberViewModel>
{
    public MemberPage(MemberViewModel memberViewModel) :
        base(viewModel: memberViewModel, pageTitle: memberViewModel.Title)
    {
        Style = AppStyles.ContentPageStyle;

        Content = new ScrollView()
        {
            Content = new VerticalStackLayout()
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,

                Children =
                {
                    new Label()
                    {
                    }
                    .Bind(Label.TextProperty, 
                        static (MemberViewModel vm) => vm.Member.FirstName, mode: BindingMode.OneWay),

                    new Label()
                    {
                    }
                    .Bind(Label.TextProperty,
                        static (MemberViewModel vm) => vm.Member.LastName, mode: BindingMode.OneWay)
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In the ViewModel, if this line is enabled:
//OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Member));
then the updates are not reflected in the UI.

However, if I specify the attributes in the model explicitly:

```cs
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Member.FirstName));
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Member.LastName));
```

then they are reflected in the UI.
Why does the OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Member)) not work?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't fully understand the question. But could you check the result of `_MembersService.GetMemberAsync` for us? The `Member` property should have a 'default value' since you use `MemberModel member = new()`. And if it builds the page before getting the data, `Member` will keep the original value, so it won't be `null`. The fact might be that the returned data is just `null`.

Comment: Hi yes the service works fine as mentioned above.  It sets the Member when the query attribute is retrieved.  However, the page has already been loaded and doesn;t seem to be notified that the Member has changed,

Comment: So the problem is that `memberViewModel.Member` has changed but the things on the screen is not updated? Well... So how do you bind the property? The given code is just about the title.

Comment: Hi, yeah fair point!  I've edited the code above to show the binding

Comment: I've updated the code sample above and found one ugly workaround to add OnPropertyChanged for each field within the model Member.  I would expect it to work when the OnPropertyChanged for the Model Member is executed.

Comment: umm... maybe it only subscribed to the member's `PropertyChanged`, but not the view model's? I'm considering whether it's a problem (or maybe a feature) of the community toolkit... I don't expect this to happen when using `xaml`...

Comment: well it might be that. I have found `CommunityToolkit.Maui.Markup.TypedBindingExtensions.GetMemberName` just returns `memberExpression.Member.Name`, without recursively accessing the whole expression. But I'm not sure whether it's a bug or a feature. Maybe we should ask for it in the project's issues.

Answer (score 0):

> However, if I specify the attributes in the model explicitly:
> OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Member.FirstName));
> OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Member.LastName)); then they are reflected in
> the UI. Why does the OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Member)) not work?

From the code you shared, I couldn't reproduce this problem.

But you can first recheck the bind way you used.

You can refer to the following code:

```
    <Label  Text="{Binding Member.FirstName}"/>

    <Label  Text="{Binding Member.LastName}"/>
```

Then we don't need call `OnPropertyChanged`, we can just do as follows.

Once the value of `Member` changes, the UI will refresh itself.

```
try
    {
        if (!(await HasInternetAccessAsync()))
            return;

        IsBusy = true;

        Member = await _membersService.GetMemberAsync(id: id);

        //OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Member));
        //OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Member.FirstName));
        //OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Member.LastName));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I'm using C# markup so it may be something specific to that because this worked when it was using XAML.  I tried the following from the community toolkit binding doc and this worked without the OnPropertyChanged, although it is quite verbose.  See example below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work using this binding from the community toolkit examples.  It is verbose but avoids the explicit OnPropertyChanged.

```
                    new Label()
                {
                }
                .Bind(
                    targetProperty: Label.TextProperty,
                    getter: static (MemberViewModel vm) => vm.Member.FirstName,
                        handlers: new (Func<MemberViewModel, object?>, string)[]
                         {
                            (vm => vm, nameof(MemberViewModel.Member)),
                            (vm => vm.Member, nameof(MemberViewModel.Member.FirstName)),
                         },
                    setter: static (MemberViewModel vm, string text) => vm.Member.FirstName = text),
```